# Правильно ли употреблён глагол "иллюстрировать"?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов

Правильно ли употреблён глагол "иллюстрировать" в предложении "Какая песня иллюстрирует печальные Post Mortem Photography"?

На YouTube, нечаянно нарвалась: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07hNTSNDzaE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [ИЛЛЮСТРИРОВАТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), -рую, -руешь; иллюстрированный; -ван, -а, -о; св. и нсв. кого-что (чем). 1. Снабдить - снабжать иллюстрациями (2 зн.). И. Пушкина. И. рассказ, книгу. 2. (св. также проиллюстрировать). Пояснить - пояснять наглядным примером, послужить - служить поясняющим образцом. И. разбираемый вопрос конкретными примерами. <Иллюстрироваться, -руется; страд. Иллюстрирование, -я; ср. И. книг. И. журналов. Иллюстрация (см.).
>
> [ИЛЛЮСТРАЦИЯ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), -и; ж. [лат. illustratio - наглядное изображение, живое описание] 1. =Иллюстрирование. Заниматься иллюстрацией книг. 2. Рисунок в тексте книги, журнала, сопровождающий изложение или поясняющий содержание. Книга с иллюстрациями. Иллюстрации известного графика. 3. Пример, наглядно поясняющий что-л. Убедительные иллюстрации лектора. <Иллюстративный (см.). Иллюстрационный, -ая, -ое.

1. Иллюстрировать в значении "снабжать иллюстрациями". Песня ничем не снабжает. Песня также не служит иллюстрацией в прямом смысле слова, так как она не является визуальным объектом.

Осторожно предположу, что можно сказать: **песня служит музыкальной иллюстрацией к фотографиям**, вводя образное выражение "музыкальная иллюстрация" по аналогии с "музыкальной картинкой". Но именно *служит иллюстрацией*, а не *иллюстрирует*. А вот и пример в Нацкорпусе нашелся:

> Поэтому опера «Мать» не стала событием, хотя она имеет все права считаться хорошей **музыкальной иллюстрацией** к повести Горького. [И. А. Груздев. Заметки по поводу оперы В. Желобинского «Мать» (1939.01.16) // «Советское искусство». № 8 (588), 1939]

2. Иллюстрировать в значении "служить поясняющим образцом". В этом смысле песня может иллюстрировать чье-то песенное творчество. Может быть, сюжет песни что-то иллюстрирует? Тут надо разобраться, о чем Post Mortem Photography. Есть ли в них какая-то философская идея, исллюстрацией которой служит сюжет данной песни. Но ведь в клипе песня служит фоном для видеоряда, вряд ли корректно говорить о примере, образце.
3. Наиболее вероятный вариант: автор текста не понимает значения слова *иллюстрировать*. А следовало бы сказать: песня сопровождает, служит фоном, аккомпанементом, музыкальным оформлением, передает эмоциональную составляющую печальных фотографий.

Comment: Спасибо, помог. Вот тебе за это: http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82&all=x